# Input Dates to an SQL Query through R

Tags: sql, r, date

Hello I am trying to paste dates into an SQL query within R. MY code is as follows:

```
Date1<-'20171031'
Date2<-'20170731' 

SQLCommand<- data.frame(sqlQuery(myConn, "SELECT fc.[FactSet Fund Code], fc.FactsetDate,  fc.[Asset Class], fc.[Fund Manager], d.Id AS DeskID, d.[Name] AS DeskName, c.ClosingDate, m.NumericGrossPerformanceTarget, fc.[% Factor Risk], fc.[Predicted Tracking Error], fc.[Portfolio Predicted Beta]    
                             FROM [PortfolioAnalytics].[Data_Factset].[FundChar] fc 
                             LEFT OUTER JOIN Data_Axioma.FactSetAccount fsa ON fc.FactsetAccountCode = REPLACE(fsa.Code, '_', '') 
                             LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Portfolio p ON fsa.PortfolioId = p.Id 
                             LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Mandate m ON p.UnderlyingId = m.id 
                             INNER JOIN dbo.Mandate c ON p.UnderlyingId = c.id 
                             LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Desk d ON m.DeskId = d.Id
                             WHERE IncludesCash = 1 
                             AND [FactSet Fund Code] IS NOT NULL 
                             AND [Fund Manager] IS NOT NULL 
                             AND [Asset Class] IS NOT NULL 
                             AND FactsetDate IN ("Date1, Date2")
                             ORDER BY [Predicted Tracking Error] DESC"))
```

I get an unexpected symbol error.

Answer (score 1):

To do this with string manipulation

```
Date1 <- "20171031"
Date2 <- "20170731" 

query <- sprintf("select * from yourtable
                  where column between '%s' and '%s'", Date1, Date2)
```

Comment: Can you use my above example? Not sure I am following you here

Comment: Try replacing the single quotes and change the reference

Comment: I have replaced with double quotes and still nothing. Sorry but what do you mean by change the reference?